# Deploy to BFTP-Server with Maven fails due to write protection

Tags: maven, deployment, ftp

I have a jetty 8 server running on an archlinux VM. I installed bftpd as FTP server and configured my maven project as follows:

```
...
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>personal-ftp-repository</id>
        <url>ftp://www.example.com</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
...
<extension>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
</extension>
...
```

The repo with the name given for distributionManagement is correctly defined in my settings.xml and the deploy works as it is correctly uploading the assembled WAR when running mvn deploy.

But the uploaded file gets unwanted file permissions. I have set the bftpd UMASK to 000 which leads to a file permission of 777 on uploaded directories, 666 on uploaded files. But these are not executable by the server and therefore jetty fails to serve them.

When I manually switch the WAR file's permissions to 777 the file is served as intended. But when I then try to upload a newer version of the WAR via mvn deploy it reports that 
    FTP Server response: 553 Error: Remote file is write protected.
even if the jetty server has been stopped.

There must be a way to deploy the WAR without manually deleting the old one, deploying and then having to manually set the file permissions but I can't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the DELE command for FTP is disabled in BFTPD. Turning it on in /etc/bftpd.conf resolved the failing deploy. So it seems like the deploy goal first tries to delete the old file and then upload the newer one. Didn't know that either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what service you are using, but if you're using tomcat..
Maybe you can try this one..

1. Open cmd,
2. Navigate to the directory where the pom.xml exist
3. Type command --> mvn clean install tomcat:deploy. (Use tomcat:undeploy tomcat:deploy, or simply tomcat:redeploy, on subsequent runs to first remove the previous deployment.)

This single command string does all of the following:

- Deletes the service/target output folder if it already exists (same as mvn clean alone)
- Recreates the folder and generates and compiles the Java classes into it (mvn package)
- Creates a WAR file for the web service provider and JAR file
- Installs the JAR and WAR into your local Maven repository (mvn install)
- Undeploys the previous WAR file (if also using tomcat:undeploy or tomcat:redeploy)
- Deploys the new WAR file onto Tomcat. (mvn tomcat:deploy)

Comment: The service/container is Jetty and as I understand it from [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin) there is no goal for redeploying to a remote Jetty instance

Comment: Have you made sure that the right directory and file already had the permission (I'm afraid your FTP Server response error 553 was caused by giving wrong file/directory permission)...

Comment: This was not the case (see my answer) but thanks for the idea.